Need help returning a 2D array of structs in C
I am pretty new to C and don't fully understand it. I think I need to allocate memory for the 2D array I want to return but am unsure how and pretty stumped. This is the whole code I have, but the trouble should be with my createInstructions method. In my IDE it says "array type has incomplete element type 'instructions[]'" and "declaration of 'instructs' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first". I don't fully understand what these mean or how to go about fixing them. Any advice is appreciated.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char getString(char fileName[]) {
    char string[1000];
    fopen(fileName, "r");
    fscanf("%s", string);
    return string;
}

typedef struct Tape {
    char value;
    struct Tape *next;
    struct Tape *previous;
} Tape;

typedef struct instructions {
    char writeState;
    char movement;
    char newState;
} instructions;

typedef struct data {
    char string[1000];
    char fileName[100];
    int numStates, startState, endState;
} data;


data* createData(char fileName[]) {

    data* d = (data*)malloc(sizeof(data));
    strcpy(d->fileName, fileName);
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    fscanf(file, "%s", d->string);
    fscanf(file, "%d", &d->numStates);
    fscanf(file, "%d", &d->startState);
    fscanf(file, "%d", &d->endState);

    fclose(file);
    return d;
}

void testData(data* d) {
    printf("String: %s\n", d->string);
    printf("Start State: %d\n", d->startState);
    printf("End State: %d\n", d->endState);
    printf("Number of States: %d\n", d->numStates);
    printf("File Name: %s\n", d->fileName); // Correctly print fileName
}

Tape* createTape(char c) {
    Tape* newTape = malloc(sizeof(Tape));
    newTape->value = c;
    newTape->next = NULL;
    newTape->previous = NULL;
    return newTape;
}

Tape* stringToTape(char string[]) {
    if (string[0] != 'A') {
        printf("Invalid input, tape must begin with A\n");
        return NULL;
    }
        Tape* head = createTape(string[0]);
        Tape* curr = head;
        for (int i = 1; i < strlen(string); i++) {
            curr->next = createTape(string[i]);
            curr->next->previous = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    return head;
}

instructions *createInstructions(data d) {
    char moveVal, writeState, readState, newState, currentState;
    FILE *file = fopen(d.fileName, "r");
    int numStates = d.numStates;
    char endState = d.endState;
    char cur = d.startState;

    instructions instructs[numStates - 1][127];

    while (cur != endState) {
        fscanf(file,"%d %d %d %d %d", &currentState,&readState,&writeState,&moveVal,&newState);
        instructs[currentState][readState].writeState = writeState;
        instructs[currentState][readState].movement = moveVal;
        instructs[currentState][readState].newState = newState;
        cur = newState;
    }

    fclose(file);
    return *instructs;
}

Tape* processTape(instructions instructs[][], Tape* head, data* d) {

    char endState = d->endState;
    char currentState = d->startState;
    char curVal = head->value;

    Tape* temp = head;

    while (currentState != endState) {
        temp->value = instructs[currentState][curVal].writeState;
        if (instructs[currentState][curVal].movement == 'R') {
            temp->next->previous = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if (instructs[currentState][curVal].movement == 'L') {
            temp->previous->next = temp;
            temp = temp->previous;
        }
        currentState = instructs[currentState][curVal].newState;
        curVal = temp->value;
    }
    return head;
}

    void print_tape(Tape* head) {
        Tape *temp = head;
        while (temp->previous != NULL) {
            temp = temp->previous;
            while(temp!=NULL) {
                printf("%c", temp->value);
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
    }

int main() {
    return 0;
}


Save time. 1)  enable all compiler warnings to quickly identify broken code like fscanf("%s", string); and others.  2) Check return value of all input functions like fscanf().

return string; is invalid. You can't return a local array.

The proposed dupe has something in common (e.g. returning pointers to objects with automatic storage duration) but the dupe doesn't address multi-dimentional arrays. Nor does it address the specific messages that OP gets from the IDE. Until a better dupe is found I propose a reopen.

There are several problems with your code. Enable all compiler warnings, e.g. gcc -Wall -Wextra  -Werror -pedantic .... For your specific question, i.e. array type has incomplete element type 'instructions[] it comes from this line: Tape* processTape(instructions instructs[][], Tape* head, data* d). The problem is the [][] part. C requires that you give a size for all dimensions except the first. Actual that's exactly what the other message says: multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first. If you write, e.g. [][127] that warning will go away but ...

.. there are still many other problems in your code that must be fixed. For instance return string;. It returns a pointer to a local variable (variable with automatic storage duration). When that pointer is used afterwards the behavior is undefined.

Also fscanf("%s", string); is wrong. Maybe you wanted just scanf("%s", string);. That said, I'll strongly advice you to avoid using scanf/fscanf. Just forget all about them.

Welcome to SO. "This is the whole code I have" This is not useful as it contains lots of unrelated code that only takes extra time when everyone needs to read it just to find out it is not relevant. Please always reduce your code to the bare minimum required to demonstrate your issue. All that code related to printing, reading data from file etc. is not related to returning an array from your function. See MCVE for more details.

Always check if fopen() was successful or not.

As also described in another answer by @MikeNakis C requires that the array size is given for all dimension except the first. So [][] won't work. You need to tell the size of the second dimension like [][SOME_NUMBER].
Also notice that returning a pointer to a local variable is real bad. When the function returns the variable doesn't exist anymore. So if you try to access it using the returned pointer, the behavior is undefined.
There are more problems in your code (check all warnings) but I'll focus on this part:

Need help returning a 2D array of structs in C

If you want a function to create a 2D array with variable number of rows and "return it" to the caller, you need dynamic allocation.
C doesn't (directly) support returning arrays. So instead you return a pointer to the dynamic allocated memory.
The "tricky" part here is the type of that pointer. It has to be a pointer to the first element of the array.
So what is the first element of a 2D array? It's a 1D array. So what you need is a pointer to a "normal" 1 dimensional array. It looks like this:
#define COLUMN_SIZE 4

TYPE (*p)[COLUMN_SIZE];

Now p is a pointer to an array with COLUMN_SIZE elements of type TYPE.
But notice all you have is a pointer. So far there is no memory holding the array itself. You can get the memory using dynamic allocation - see later.
The above is the syntax for a "pointer to array". But we actually wanted a function that could return such a pointer. It looks like this:
TYPE (*create(unsigned sz))[]

where sz is the number of elements (aka 1D arrays or number of rows in the 2D array) to allocate and create is the function returning a "pointer to array".
The function body will do the dynamic allocation and return the pointer. Like:
#define COLUMN_SIZE 4
#define ROW_SIZE 8

TYPE (*create(unsigned sz))[] {
    TYPE (*p)[COLUMN_SIZE];

    // Allocate sz arrays with COLUMN_SIZE elements of type TYPE
    p = malloc(sz * sizeof(*p));

    return p;
}

void foo(void) {
    TYPE (*arr2D)[COLUMN_SIZE] = create(ROW_SIZE);

    // Now arr2D can be used as a 2D array as if you had done
    //     TYPE arr2D[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE]
    // Example:
    arr2D[1][2] = something;
    ...

    free(arr2D);  // Dynamic allocated memory must be freed when done with it
}

Here is a code example that looks more like your code (a bit simplified but similar):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COLUMN_SIZE 4
#define ROW_SIZE 3

typedef struct instructions {
    int data;
} instructions;

instructions (*createInstructions(unsigned num))[]  {
    instructions (*instructs)[COLUMN_SIZE] = malloc(num * sizeof(*instructs));
    return instructs;
}

int main(void) {
    instructions (*arr2D)[COLUMN_SIZE] = createInstructions(ROW_SIZE);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; ++j) {
            arr2D[i][j].data = 10 * i + j;
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; ++j) {
            printf("%3d ", arr2D[i][j].data);
        }
        puts("");
    }
    
    return 0;
}

Output:
  0   1   2   3 
 10  11  12  13 
 20  21  22  23 


At a low level, arrays in C are in fact one-dimensional, and the [][] syntax is provided by the compiler as a convenience. However, the compiler can only use the [][] syntax if all dimensions (except the first) are known during compilation time.
So, if you want to use an array but none of the dimensions is known during compilation time, then you cannot use the [][] syntax, and you have to fall back to one-dimensional arrays.
The following example code demonstrates how to do this.
In this example, we use a one-dimensional array to represent a two-dimensional array. The mechanism is the same for any number of dimensions.
In this example, array elements are of type int. The mechanism is the same for any type of array element, including struct.
The function allocate_2d_array_of_int_and_fill_with_ascending_value() allocates an array with given width and height, and it initializes each array element with a given ascending value.
The function address_of_2d_array_element() returns the address of an element at given x, y coordinates within the array. It calculates a one-dimensional index based on the requested coordinates and the width of the array, and returns the address of the array element at that index. Strictly speaking, the function does not need the height of the array for the calculation, but the height is also passed for the purpose of index bounds checking.
The function main() allocates such an array using 42 as the initial ascending value, and then prints the array.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int* address_of_2d_array_element( int* array, int w, int h, int x, int y )
{
    assert( x >= 0 && x < w );
    assert( y >= 0 && y < h );
    return &array[y * w + x];
}

int* allocate_2d_array_of_int_and_fill_with_ascending_value( int w, int h, int start_value )
{
    int* array = malloc( w * h * sizeof(int) );
    for( int y = 0;  y < h;  y++ )
        for( int x = 0;  x < w;  x++ )
            *address_of_2d_array_element( array, w, h, x , y ) = start_value++;
    return array;
}

int main(void)
{
    const int w = 3;
    const int h = 2;
    int* array = allocate_2d_array_of_int_and_fill_with_ascending_value( w, h, 42 );
    for( int y = 0;  y < h;  y++ )
    {
        for( int x = 0;  x < w;  x++ )
        {
            int value = *address_of_2d_array_element( array, w, h, x, y );
            printf( "%3d ", value );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
    free( array );
    return 0;
}

The above code prints the following:
 42  43  44 
 45  46  47 

Here it is on Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/vMaxWxfqn

all dimensions (except the first) are known during compilation time is only true for legacy ANSI C standard.

@tstanisl well then feel free to give an answer different from mine.
